# Lightweight & Fast REST Server library for java?

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, rest, servlets

I'm looking for a lightweight REST library.

It must be small (in kb size) an Fast (in total execution time). The optimal solution is a single jar without any dependencies what so ever.

The application is designed to run on the AppEngine so the library should work on GAE/J platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.restlet.org/  I have no idea if it will run on the Google App Engine.

Comment: @Avi Thanks for the clarification.  I didn't even know Google App Engine could run Java stuff :-)

Comment: I've looked at restlet, the link from the "Will it play on AppEngine" points to this location http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.2/13-restlet/252-restlet.html which resolves to a 404... Generally I couldn't find any good documentation.

Comment: @Maxim  http://blog.noelios.com/2009/12/17/restlet-a-restful-middleware-for-gwt-gae-and-android/

Comment: @Maxim that's because they changed the version number of 1.2 to 2.0. But yeah, they should have redirects on those doc pages. Here's the correct URL: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/252-restlet.html

Comment: Restlet is in a pretty desperate state like now. Documentation is only available over wayback machine ...

Answer (score 5):

Try Jersey

https://jersey.dev.java.net/

http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features

https://jersey.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html

http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/820-4867/820-4867.pdf

Its extensive use of Java annotations massively reduces the amount of
boilerplate needed.

Comment: To clarify, the annotations are a feature of the JAX-RS standard, of which Jersey is simply an implementation. Other implementations exist, such as Restlet.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this ever helps anyone check out [jrest-server](http://code.google.com/p/jrest-server/) , its a rest server ontop of appengine for java.

Answer (score 0):

I love play framework 2.0. Easily, convert a static method into a rest call. Powerful routing mechanism. Serve webpages as well as rest calls.