# REST server framework for Android

Tags: java, android, rest

I am working on an embedded device which has Android OS on it, Its not a smartphone. I need to write a webserver in android for which I am using iJetty. I am planning to have service expose as REST webservice. For this I am looking at light weight REST server framework that I can use inside by apk file.

I did some research and found [Restlets for Android](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html)

Do you know of any good light weight REST server framework that you would like to recommend?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881338/lightweight-fast-rest-server-library-for-java

Comment: And this one seems to be even more related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097686/restful-frameworks-for-android-ios?rq=1